# What's the proper format for the "date" datatype?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes

My model "User" has a date attribute `:birthday`. But if I submit a birthday with any format other than `x/x/x`, it just becomes nil. So, for example, `1/1/1` becomes "0001-01-01", but `1/1/15` becomes nil. `1/1/2` becomes "0001-01-02", but `22/1/3` becomes nil.

I feel like I'm missing something here. It can't possibly be true that date attributes can only be `x/x/x`, right?

Comment: Usually you're supposed to submit a `Date` or `Time` (or `DateTime`), not a `String`.

Comment: @Manuel So how does "1/1/1" work when "1/1/15" doesn't?

Comment: I have no Idea. Maybe this is related to the DB you're using. That's why you should submit a Date; see Max William's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting the date?  Is it something like `@user.birthday = params[:birthday]`?  This is going to cause you problems because it's not a date, it's a string, and a string in a different format to how your database stores the date, at that.

You've got two options:

A) Ideally you should convert the input to a date, and then set the field using the actual date object.

B) make sure the format of your parameter matches how your db stores dates (which is "yyyy-mm-dd" by the looks of it).

A is preferable.  I would override the User#birthday= method to try to get it to process the date as usefully as possible.  eg

```
#in User model
 def birthday=(arg)
   if arg.is_a?(Date)
     self[:birthday] = arg
   elsif arg =~ /\d+\/\d+\/\d+/
     self[:birthday] = Date.strptime(arg, "%d/%m/%y")
   elsif arg =~ /\d+\-\d+\-\d+/
     self[:birthday] = Date.strptime(arg, "%y/%m/%d")
   else
     self[:birthday] = arg
   end
 end
```

Comment: At this point I'm just trying to set it using the rails console, so like this: `$ User.create(birthday: "1/1/15")`. Why would "1/1/1" work, in that case?

Comment: Rails will try it's best to convert it to a date, but it's likely to get it wrong.  Maybe it's expecting the last number to be the month, and 15 isn't a valid month.  Either way, it doesn't really matter - you need to make sure that it will **always** work by either giving it a string in the format it expects or giving it an actual Date object.